# Android uses-feature fingerprint required=false parsing error

Tags: android, fingerprint

In my app I use the FingerprintManager.

In the manifest I have declared the uses-feature and the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint" android:required="false" />
```

It all works fine on devices with fingerprint hardware. It also works fine if I install the app by AndroidStudio on a device without the fingerprint hardware.

The problem is when I try to install the .apk on a device without fingerprint hardware I get either a parsing error or a simple message "App was not installed."

What can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

I had to check V1 (JAR signature) on the second page of 'Build signed APK' in AndroidStudio.